# underflow and Overflow

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
 float f(int x)
 {
      return 1 / (2 * x);
 }
```

1. The minimum possible value of x that doesn't cause an underflow is:
   x = (MinValue/______)
2. The minimum possible value of x that doesn't cause an overflow is: x
   = (MaxValue /_____)

And an error case between the boundaries is: x =

Here I Thouge

> Underflow  X = MINvalue/0
>    OverFlow  X = MINvalue/2

Error X =-2

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please clear with the question and the proper out put u needed, is it homework for u.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't apply to your computation. You are computing on integral numbers versus real numbers. See picture here:

[image]